# Translation doesn't propagate to tab labels

Tags: c++, qt

I am facing a weird issue with qt where I have successfully added support for different languages using QTranslator. It is having a tabwidget with first tab created using qt designer form. The problem is everytime I try to change language everything works fine except the titles of tabs that I have added using

`QTabWidget->addTab(QWidget *widget, widget->windowTitle() )`.

I have handled the `changeEvent(Event *)` inside each widget and call `ui->retransalteUI()` when ever Language change is encountered and it updates everything except title . Badly need help.

Comment: Maybe the Title does not get updated in the automatic created function `retranslateUI();` Try setting the Title again yourself in case of an language Update event using `widget->setTitle(tr("YOUR TITLE STRING"));`

Answer (score 3):

You need to propagate the changes in the `windowTitle` to the tab's label.

For example:

```
void addTitledTab(QTabWidget * tabWidget, QWidget * widget) {
  int index = tabWidget->addTab(widget, widget->windowTitle());
  QObject::connect(widget, &QWidget::windowTitleChanged, 
    [index, tabWidget](const QString & text){
    tabWidget->setTabText(index, text);
  });
}
```